# Calling getView() method in custom ListView

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, custom-lists

I am using custom `ListView` with text and arrow image at right of the list row.

I have the following

> 1: MainActivity extends ListActivity
>
> 2: SpecialAdapter extends ArrayAdapter have getView() method.
>
> 3: classes for Sqlite Database.

I have an `EditText` and add `Button` for storing new text into database as well as to my list. Code is here.

```
 OnClickListener listenerAdd = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Comment comment = null;
            EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_txt);
            String number = edit.getText().toString();
            if(!number.equals("")){
            comment = datasource.createComment(number);
            adapter.add(comment);
            edit.setText("");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

I am totally confused that in which class I should use this code?

How to call getView method?

I used this code in main class but it throws exception.

The more important is what adapter I should to use?

Adapter Code here..

```
    public class SpecialAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Comment>{

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;   
    Comment data[]= null;
   // Comment dataCom[] = null;
    public SpecialAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,Comment[] values) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, values);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new WeatherHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.img_arrow);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Comment comment =  data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(comment.getComment());
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);

        return row;
    }

    static class WeatherHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

Comment: paste your adapter code

Comment: i added the adapter code please check. @Qadir

Comment: now tell plz. whats your question

Comment: in which class i can put the onclick listener code.

Answer (score 1):

you have to put the `onClickListner` in yourClass which is extending to `Actvity`. Also make sure that yourXML file contains that button. otherwise you will get Exception.

i.e

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourXMLLayoutFileName);
```

your button should be in the `yourXMLLayoutFileName` XML file